# 'mysql' user and group creation, ownership settings

Tags: users, mysql

I know what the linux command `chown` does, I used it to change the ownership or group of a file.

If there is a **MySQL** installation on a **Ubuntu** machine, I saw some people doing the following thing:

```
sudo chown mysql:mysql /data/tmp
```

I get confused, I know the meaning of the above command, which is to change the owner of `/data/tmp` to user '`mysql`' and change the group of it to '`mysql`' group.

But:

**1.** Why would one run the above command?
**2.** Where do the 'mysql' owner and group come from? Does the installation of MySQL on a Linux machine automatically create the 'mysql' user and group?

Comment: 2. Yes, many daemons are run with a dedicated user/group which is usually created when the package is installed.

Comment: ...and 1.) because otherwise the DBMS won't be able to read/write the data

Comment: Symcbean, do you mean those .frm .MYD .MYI files can be created by MySQL to the directory /data/tmp/  when a table created?

Comment: @symcbean why the mysql installtion itself does'nt change the ownerships automaticly at the installation stage?

Comment: @Hanan N.: typically most installers will do this at the same time as creating the users (i.e. when they're running as root). But /data/tmp is NOT a default path for any mysql data files - if you change the paths after installation, then you need to make suer that the new locations are accessible.

Comment: @Mellon: the DBMS will attempt to create the files in the locations configured for it.

Comment: @symcbean, What I wanna ask is if run command "sudo chown mysql:mysql /data/tmp", the MySQL data dir will be /data/tmp instead of /var/lib/mysql(which is the MySQL default data dir), am I right?

Answer (score 1):

The installation of the MySQL package in Ubuntu creates a `mysql` user and a group of the same name. This is the user that the MySQL daemon process runs under, and many MySQL-related files belong to that user. If you install MySQL manually, you may need to create the user yourself.

`chown mysql:mysql /data/tmp` (executed as root) makes the user `mysql` and the group `mysql` the owning user and owning group of the file or directory `/data/tmp`. I don't know why these people did it, you'd have to ask them.

Answer (score 1):

There are some reasons to do it like this way.

1. When you are installing mysql on your Linux machine. mysql user and groups installed automatically.
2. Why user/group is required for this action ? It s required for security reasons. You want to give a permission to user which one will use the mysql. And also you give the permission on /data/tmp . Because your database files stored in there by default.